# What are the principles of an event system in C++?

Tags: c++, events, signals-slots

First of all, I know there are excellent implementations (Qt, Boost, cpp-event, etc.), but I ask the question because I want to know how it works !

If I understand correctly, the "event system" uses the Observer pattern : some objects are observing, waiting for something to happen... and some others send signals. All right.

So, let's say I've got my observer class, with this kind of thing :

```
void Observer::getNotified() 
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

My question is : how to manage dynamically what kind of stuff should be done ? I've seen a lot of people saying specifically not to use functions pointers. For my current need, I can do a switch statement, a enum type, and select different behaviors, but that's not very satisfying. So, if it's not functions pointers, how is it done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of different implementations possible (whatever the language), but the abstract idea is :

1. have an event type identifier to know wich events have been fired by the observed object (it can be whatever works);
2. have a list of observers (or several, one by event type?) registered in the registered objects - that suppose that the observers are functors (function pointer or object that act like a function) or are objects with a known interface (with a virtual method to call ion event fired);
3. when an event is fired (by calling a function on the observed object) we just go through the list of observers registered for the event's type and pass the event information (id plus maybe data ) to the observer to be processed;

Here is a simplist implementation :

```
enum EventType
{
   Event_A,
   Event_B,
};

class Observer // for this example i'll suppose observer inherits this class
{
    virtual void catchEvent( EventType e ) = 0; // for sake of the example I just need the event type, not the data, but it's often required

    virtual ~Observer(){}; // virtual base classes require this to work fine.
};

class Observed
{
      typedef std::vector<Observer*> ObserverList; 
      typedef std::map< EventType, ObserverList > ObserversTable;
      ObserversTable m_observers; // we have observers for each event type

public:

     void addObserver( Observer& observer, EventType eType ) 
     { m_observers[ eType ].push_back( observer ); } // this is simplist, to say the least...

     void sendEvent( EventType event ) // here we send the event, it will be catched by observers
     { // note : often this type of system is "buffered", but here we will process it immediatly as it's a simple example

        ObserverList& observers = m_observers[ event ];  
        for ( ObserverList::iterator it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); ++it )
        {
              Observer* observer = *it;
              observer->catchEvent( event ); // here an observer receive the event
        }

     }
};
```

It's really a basic example but that might help you understand the idea.

Comment: Thank you : it doesn't quite understand my question, but it'll be very helpful too.

Comment: It don't answer directly because as I said : There is a lot of different implementations possible (whatever the language)
I've implemented tons of radically different way to do it in C++ only (and other variants in other languages) and it's hard to use a specific implementation for everything.

Or maybe I didn't understood the exact point of your question? :)

Comment: @Raveline: have another look, it does answer your question: instead of using function pointers, inherit from an interface (Observer).  Then it shows how to manage dynamically what kind of stuff should be done.

Comment: @stefaanv : You're right, it does ! My mistake, I didn't grab the whole idea when I looked at the code.
@Klaim : You got it, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is what I have currently in my program. But for the implementation of `Observer::catchEvent`, I need to make a switch on the `EventType` to figure out what I need to do. If I have a lot of different event types then I could have a giant switch. Is there a way around this? Or is the switch implementation not a problem to worry about?

Comment: @wardd Yes you would need a more complex implementation but it's totally feasable. I have one online but it have specific parts , so just study how the whole works and you'll understand. The point is to have a way to gather pointers to observers of the same type of events, which mean you keep the knowledge of what is the type of the event into the type which is the group of observers. Then on dispatching you find the observer group corresponding to the event type and dispatch to them: http://pastebin.com/amFh6Bic  and http://pastebin.com/Vtw70ZSF for observers.

Comment: @wardd There is also another way to do it, more flexible but implemented with boost::signals2 (so it's naturally thread-safe), but it forces the observing code to keep handles to the connection. I have an example implementation of this in my OSS project (which is still WIP) but just ignore the functions using Id<T>, they are specific to my case - so the code could be simpler in a more generic case: https://github.com/artofsequence/aos-designer/blob/5d65377c4a42b41f4b1c9bbb5d3b07b51b9616ee/backend/include/aosdesigner/backend/tools/eventdispatcher.hpp

Comment: @wardd To summarize the idea: use typeid() (it's fast!) and type_index (c++11) to identify the type of event the observer wants to listen to, register the observer in a group (or several, for several events) related to the event's type. Then when the event is dispatched, look at it's type, retrieve the corresponding observer group, and call them with the event.

Answer (score 1):

See this rather [excellent article](http://accu.org/index.php/journals/464) from Pete Goodliffe, which routes to different methods depending on the event type being notified.

If you need to choose actions within a single event type, then typically your code would choose depending on the data passed in the notification.